# Can I change MaterialSwitch to true/false instead of on/off?

Tags: cosmicmind

Anyway I can change `MaterialSwitch` to return true/false instead of on/off?

```
print(switch.switchState) // prints true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hearing nothing else, I improvised and created a new `bool` variable.  Then I just used `if` statements to set it correctly by accessing the `hashValue`.

```
 if self.option1.switchState.hashValue == 1 {
        option1Value = false
    } else {
        option1Value = true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just run `print(not switch.switchState)`